# How to bring horizontally centered nav links closer together in Flex design?

Tags: html, css

I have found questions similar to mine but can't find a solution that will work.  I have my nav links centered horizontally in my header with my logo in the very center.  My links are spread out evenly across the width of the screen. I need to bring my nav links in closer together and closer to my logo.  I'm at a loss and don't know what else to try. This is also making my hover effect (underline) stretch out much farther than the width of each word.   Thanks in advance for your help.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
   line-height: 1.2em;
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

html, body{
  height: 100%;
}

.cc_nav {
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  height: 20%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; 
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center; 
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  font-family: Tenar Sans;
  font-size: .8em;
  flex: 1;
}

a {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative; 
  overflow: hidden; 
}

a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(192,192,192); 
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s; }


a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="cc_nav" id="centered_nav">
    <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
    <a href="services.html">SERVICES</a>
    <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
    <a href="index.html" class="noHover"><img src="images/logo_6.png" alt="Claire Crawford" id="logo_Claire" /></a>
    <a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
    <a href="blog.html">BLOG</a>
    <a href="contact.html">GET IN TOUCH</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `flex: 1` makes items grow proportionately to fill the container. You might consider using `flex: 0 0 auto` so that items cannot grow or shrink beyond their default widths.

I've also added left and right margins so that the items don't run together.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.cc_nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  height: 20%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  font-family: Tenar Sans;
  font-size: .8em;
  margin: 0 1em;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

a {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="cc_nav" id="centered_nav">
    <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
    <a href="services.html">SERVICES</a>
    <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
    <a href="index.html" class="noHover"><img src="images/logo_6.png" alt="Claire Crawford" id="logo_Claire" /></a>
    <a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
    <a href="blog.html">BLOG</a>
    <a href="contact.html">GET IN TOUCH</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

For reference, see [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex).

Incidentally, there also seems to be a typo in your code; the closing `</div>` tag shows as an opening `<div>` tag.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me.  I can't believe I missed the error on the closing div.  This definitely fixed the issue and brought the nav links in closer to the logo. Thank you again!

Comment: I'm having an issue with my logo. It has shifted over about 1/2" to the left.   All the nav links are centered well but the links on the right side are wider and those on the left. I'm wondering if this is why my logo won't center. Do you have any advice that could possibly correct this?

Comment: Each item is only as wide as its text. If you need the logo centered, you might consider a [different layout](https://jsfiddle.net/e2bsko1a/), but then the menu will likely look unbalanced. I might make all items the same width and just set a `max-width` on the nav [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/4xevntfw/).

Comment: The different layout you created is exactly what I needed. I can't thank you enough for taking the time to do that for me.

Answer (score -3):

I am on my phone now so I can't rewrite the code for you but I can recommend Bootstrap Flex Box instead. It's really helpful. Helped me many times. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/
Try this in bootstrap 4

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column">
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
```